# asciidoctor-maven-plugin: use infodoc file to include javascript in the html output

Tags: asciidoctor

I 'd like to include a custom javascript and stylesheet in my asciidoctor html output. The [infodoc](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#docinfo-file) feature looks like a good choice for this.

Where do I put the `infodoc.html` file and where do I put the javascripts/css files, so the *asciidoctor-maven-plugin* picks them up correctly? My `training.adoc` file is in `src/main/asciidoc`.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the `infodoc.html` in `src/main/asciidoc` doesn't work (at least not if there's a `training-infodoc.html` file in the same directory), but that `training-infodoc.html` file in `src/main/asciidoc` does work.

And the `css` and `js` files also just go in `src/main/asciidoc`.

Filestructure which works:

```
src/main/asciidoc
src/main/asciidoc/training.adoc
src/main/asciidoc/training-infodoc.html
src/main/asciidoc/website/trainingWebsite.css
src/main/asciidoc/website/trainingWebsite.js
```